# CSS and creating border of svg figure

Tags: css, svg

I have file with star in SVG format. How to make border of that figure(not entire square with that star) using css? Also, how make fill that image on hover effect?

I tried to add  in html:

```
<i class="favorite"></i>
```

and in scss:

```
.favorite {
  width: 17px;
  height: 16px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-size: 17px 16px;
  background: url(../../../../../assets/images/icon-star.
}
```

But I dont see anything. When i change background-color to for example red I see white star on red square. How to make it work?

Comment: I see my questing isnt good . Why are You minus me?

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D for reply. Give me a moment please for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the colours of an SVG that's included via `<img>` or `background-image`.  You'll need to include it inline in your page.  You can then change the colours using the `fill` and `stroke` properties.

```css
.square {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <svg>
    <rect class="square" x="5" y="5" width="100" height="100"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```